# IMapX Gmail SEARCH operation throws exception "Bad or not correct search query"

Tags: gmail-imap, imapx

I have used the ImapX library to SEARCH Gmail using queries like :

```
ImapX.MessageCollection msg= c.Folders["INBOX"].Search("SUBJECT <abc>", false);
```

I get the error above when I try and retrieve a message using

```
MessageCollection msg= client.Folders["INBOX"].Search("UID <abc>", false);
```

where i have previously established the UID using the MessageUID property which IMapx exposes on an specific message,  I get the same error when trying to use the MessageId property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ImapX.MessageCollection msg= c.Folders["INBOX"].Search("SUBJECT abc", false);